# SQL Coding Standards

Tags: sql, sql-server, coding-style

I recently started as a reporting analyst at a new company.  We have no documentation for our production reports (see example http://snipt.org/AnL), and the guy who wrote most of it is hostile to any suggestions. I have software development experience and the dept mgr asked me to propose some standards for our SQL, so I am soliciting ideas from the StackOverFlow community.

I think we need for every report a narrative that states exactly what information the report is supposed to provide and how it will be useful to manage the process. This requires some process documentation (such as how the billing process works) which we also do not have. I think in cases where the database query strategy is not obvious, we need a statement explaining the strategy the query uses to retrieve the data. In the end, we should have enough to so the report can be handed off to a new employee and they have what they need to run, maintain and modify the report.

Then there is the question of SQL coding standards - what should the comment header include (author, date, change history...?), and structured indents to improve clarity. Should we have change controls for these things, with code reviews and documented testing?

Comment: There's a presumption here: "what should the comment header include" - who says that a comment header should exist at all?

Comment: A little more info - the databases we query are controlled by our IT dept and the vendor that provides our main operations application, of which we do not have the source code. Our reporting dept has one database we can modify. There is no DBA in our reporting dept.

Comment: If your corporate structure requires X, Y, and Z, then provide X, Y, and Z. If it doesn't, then as I've indicated, the default response should be to provide nothing. I'm not sure (either way) how asking a question here helps you.

Comment: I asked the question here to solicit feedback about these matters from experienced SQL users, and I received some interesting and useful comments. The author of the example code defends it saying the code is self-evident and anyone to whom that is not immediately obvious is incompetent. As to the what the corporate structure requires, that is what we are trying to define.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using headers, why not source control your db schema and all of your stored procedures, views, udf's, etc?

That way you don't have to maintain the meta-data manually, which will inevitably lose integrity over time as people forget to update it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173550(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: That takes care of the change history (which is indeed silly to maintain manually). But what about "structured indents to improve clarity" and "a statement explaining the strategy the query uses"?

Comment: To the analyst who inherits one of these undocumented scripts and the associated report, the biggest challenge is answering the questions "What is this thing supposed to accomplish?" and 2) "Is it working correctly?". Often the current report user is not the one who originated the report, and in meetings I have discovered misunderstandings where the SQL script has rules and filters the report user is unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I took a good look at the query you passed, and about all I can say is "Wow!".  You surely have your work cut out for you.

Procedures like this that have little to no comments, constants embedded inline with code, ALL UPPERCASE, and sub-selects of sub-selects are nightmarish to maintain.  I'd say that whoever wrote this has got some serious job security there.

Your suggestion regarding header blocks is good.  I like to have these elements: name; original author; original date; purpose; expected inputs; expected outputs; and a complete change history including: author; change date; purpose of change.

Absolutely these should be versioned.  With the advent of modern source control systems this should be a non-issue.

Other things that are a must are descriptive comments when needed, and indenting of code.  There are plenty of good editors that indent automatically, so there's no good excuse for not doing it.

You mention code reviews and documented testing.  These are also excellent practices, but for them to be effective, you need to have a staff that is open to constructive criticism.

Kudos to you for being pro-active.  I sense you have an uphill climb from here!

Comment: If you're using source control, why do you need original author and original date? And a change history? The source control system should *already* be recording that information, in a far more structured manner than "header blocks"

Comment: And for the remainder - "expected inputs; expected outputs" - if that's not clear from the naming of the procedure and its parameters, then that's a failure in your naming. That's not something that is fixed by putting petty comments (that will never, actually, be read) on the procedure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I agree not to put the change history, but I think the original author and anyone who does a lot of changes should put their name on the file. I think coders are more likely to buy in to doing a good job when their name is on the product (and the auto-generated docs?) than when it's buried in VCS. Always found it ironic that the _Soviet Union_ named stuff after designers (Kalashnikov, Tupolev, etc.) but American engineers are generally anonymous.

Comment: STL thanks for the comment. Regarding "...you need to have a staff that is open to constructive criticism.", we definitely have an opportunity there. Andrew, thanks for your comments we ownership and accountability.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual to be in a situation where software exists to solve your problem (TFS, for instance), but for one reason or another you cannot use it in your environment.  There are ways to abuse source code control software -- say the rogue developer starts running all reports out of "his" sandbox.  And, version control software does not solve all of your problems.  It has nothing to say about comments in code or naming conventions, for instance.

Here are some "standards" for helping with database software maintenance:

When version control software is not allowed, I have a comment block that describes the change history.  It looks like:

```
/*
 * GSL 2013-06-08   Modified foo at Jean's request
 * GSL 2013-06-01   Created
 */
```

This applies to views, stored procedures, and user defined functions.  If I notice a change without a comment, then I use the "embarrass in email or in person" approach to cajole adherence.

The following are not related to version control.

Naming Conventions:  The same thing in different tables always has the same name.  Even primary keys.  In general, I name a table in the plural and then remove the "s" and add "id" for the primary key.

Column conventions:  Almost all tables have a primary key (the singular form of the table name with "id" appended) and `CreatedAt` and `CreatedBy` columns.  The latter answer the question:  "What was the last thing done?" and "Who dunnit?"

Column prefixes:  For tables where the source columns come from outside the database, I use a prefix to indicate where they came from.  Something like `jl_telephonenumber` for the telephone number of something that came from Jane's list.

Catching errors:  I wrap my stored procedures in `try/catch` blocks and attempt to handle errors locally.  Typically, stored procedures take a `status` and `ErrMsg` output variables, so I can pass back status information to the caller.  And, the caller *always* checks status.

Indentation:  This is religious, and I have my religion.  There is a certain advantage to having written a book with a very particular indentation style, which is the one that I use.  I am experienced enough to know that a particular style cannot be imposed on everyone.  However, the code must be clear and must be able to clearly distinguish subquery blocks from each other.

Table aliases:  Eschew `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, `z`.  The aliases should be the abbreviation of the tables in question.

Finally (for now), if you really want to guarantee the accuracy of code, then you should institute code reviews.  This would be a 60'ish minute meeting once per week that would go through one report and discuss the coding aspects of the report.  In all likelihood, such reviews will prove extremely valuable by pointing out deficiencies in the existing reports.